# Fredholm operator's measurablility derivation

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Let $(a,b)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ bounded, let $K(x,y):(a,b)\times(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a kernel, consider the operator $T:L^2(a,b)\to L^2(a,b)$, $f\mapsto g(x)=\int_{(a,b)} f(y)K(x,y) \, dy$  if
$$K\in L^2(a,b)\times(a,b)\Bigg(i.e.\, \int_a^b\int_a^b |K(x,y)|^2\,dxdy<+\infty \Bigg)$$
then $T$ is well-defined meaning $\mathcal{I}mT\subseteq L^2(a,b)$, linear and continuous
$$Tf(x)=\int_a^bf(y)K(x,y)dy\leq\int_a^b|f(y)||K(x,y)|dy\leq(\int_a^b|f(y)|^2dy)^{\frac{1}{2}}(\int_a^b|K(x,y)|^2dy)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
hence
$$|Tf(x)|^2\leq\|f\|^2_{L^2}\int_a^b|K(x,y)|^2dy$$
then we take the integral of both sides:
$$\int_a^b|Tf(x)|^2dx\leq\int_a^b(\|f\|^2_{L^2}\int_a^b|K(x,y)|^2dy)dx$$
I do not understand if we can put out the integrals $\|f\|^2_{L^2}$ and why, and then apply Fubini-Tonelli to get on the r.h.s
$$\|f\|^2_{L^2}\int_a^b\int_a^bK(x,y)dydx$$
My questions are:

1. Can I pull (and why) the norm of $f$ out of the integral and why (I feel like it is already a number and does not vary under the integral but since it is an integral itself by definition I have doubts and feel uncomfortable because of it)
2. when I wrote in the beginning "be a kernel" I was not sure, I suppose that it is positive-definite kernel, is it right?
3. (EDITED) I am trying to narrow what is a Fredholm operator. I see that $T$ should satisfy $$\|T\|^2\leq\|K\|^2_{L^2}$$
   I do not understand what does the kernel here for $K$ mean and what are the constraints for $K,$ now I see only $L^2$ integrability

Comment: Yes $\|f\|_{L^2}^2$ is a constant so by linearity of the integral you can have it be out. And $K$ does not need to be positive-definite for what you're doing.

Comment: @BrunoB Thank you! Then what are the constraints for $K$? Only $L^2$ measurability?

Comment: $L^2$ integrability is the only thing you want here for what you've done yes. I think the use of "let $K : (a,b)^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a kernel" at the beginning is just synonymous to "let $K : (a,b)^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function", and then the claim is "if $K$ is $L^2$ then blahblahblah".